# FFMPEG wont play the rtsp link, but the same link works in VLC

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a rtsp link from an ip cam.
rtsp://admin:admin1234@192.168.2.254:82/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1

The link works fine in VLC media player but it does not play using the ffplay command. It shows a 404 error.

But  rtsp://admin:admin1234@192.168.2.254:82/live ,  will work inside ffmpeg and vlc without any issues.

Does ffmpeg only support /live or something? why doesnt my first link work? Thank you for your time.

ffplay code

```
ffplay -i rtsp://admin:admin1234@192.168.2.254:82/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1
```

error that i get

```
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[rtsp @ 000002663268f600] method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Not Found/0
rtsp://admin:admin1234@192.168.2.254:82/cam/realmonitor?channel=1: Server returned 404 Not Found

'subtype' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Escaping!

ffplay -i "rtsp://admin:admin1234@192.168.2.254:82/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1"