# "method DESCRIBE failed: 401 Unauthorized" in Ffmpeg, yet VLC accepts the exact same RTSP URL

Tags: ffmpeg

I've an RTSP URL that includes the username and password (i.e. of the form `rtsp://username:password@server:554/path`) and this works in VLC, but using this as an input to Ffmpeg, I get back the above DESCRIBE error and it aborts.

I wondered if it might be the version of Ffmpeg I've got, but I used a fresh one via Docker (`alfg/ffmpeg:latest`) and the result was the same.

Is there something I have to do, perhaps some extra information/hint I have to provide to Ffmpeg, to get it to accept the credentials and get past the DESCRIBE?  Or if it's the DESCRIBE bit that's the problem, can I get it to skip that (perhaps by providing all the source stream details manually) so that it doesn't fail?

I'd hoped that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66594263/1999993) might be the same problem, but it's not - my URL is quoted and doesn't contain anything like `?` or `*`.

(In case it has any bearing, I'm trying to take an RTSP stream that requires credentials, resize it on the fly using Ffmpeg, and "pipe" the new RTSP to RTSP Simple Server.  Most of this I can do: it's just the credentials that are tripping me up.)

**UPDATE 1:** One thing I didn't mention previously (because it didn't seem relevant) is that the RTSP stream comes from Milestone's Open Network Bridge server.  It seems that ONB does not now allow URLs containing credentials, although this does not explain why the same URL works in VLC.  Perhaps VLC extracts the credentials and provides them another way?  I've a support case open on this to try to get to the bottom of it.  I'll update here if I discover anything helpful...

**UPDATE 2:** I think I might be onto something now.  From a [Milestone support article](https://developer.milestonesys.com/s/article/changes-digest-authentication-RTSP-service-in-2021-R1-troubleshooting), it seems that Ffmpeg can't cope with there being more than one option for `WWW-Authenticate`, and my Wireshark investigations revealed that the headers that the client receives when trying the initial DESCRIBE call include:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="RtspServerLibrary", nonce="3JY4rKzboHUqFVrC9yZuSAeUpGiun3BT", algorithm="MD5"
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="RtspServerLibrary", nonce="3JY4rKzboHUqFVrC9yZuSAeUpGiun3BT", algorithm="SHA-256"
```

So that's two `WWW-Authenticate` options, and Ffmpeg fails to authenticate.  I've implemented the suggested fix and am currently trying to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, using Milestone Open Network Bridge Server, the solution was to follow the instructions in [this support article](https://developer.milestonesys.com/s/article/changes-digest-authentication-RTSP-service-in-2021-R1-troubleshooting), adding a registry key to tell ONB not to give more than one option for `WWW-Authenticate`.

That appears to be the underlying problem: `ffmpeg` cannot cope with more than one `WWW-Authenticate` header in the 401 response for the `DESCRIBE` request.  I used Wireshark to inspect the communication between `ffmpeg` and the ONB Server, and found that the headers included:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="RtspServerLibrary", nonce="3JY4rKzboHUqFVrC9yZuSAeUpGiun3BT", algorithm="MD5"
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="RtspServerLibrary", nonce="3JY4rKzboHUqFVrC9yZuSAeUpGiun3BT, algorithm="SHA-256"
```

and that's why `ffmpeg` failed: because there were two `WWW-Authenticate` headers.

---

**UPDATE:** It could actually be that the second header overwrites the first, and Ffmpeg can't do SHA256.  See [this comment](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9127#comment:4) in a bug report.